# C++ STL map in a map in a map not inserting properly

Tags: stl, maps

I am making a program that uses maps to hold and organize a music library from a text file. An artist map holds an album map which holds a song map. The problem I am having is that every album for every artist is inserted under each artist rather than just the albums for that artist. I've narrowed it down to this function that determines if the artist is new and inserts it in the artist map if it is. Same for the Albums and the songs once the albums are straightened out.

Here is my class information

```
class Song {
public:

    string title;
    int time;
    int track;
};

class Album {
public:
    map <int, Song *> songs;
    string name;
    int time;
};

class Artist {
public:
    map <string, Album *> albums;
    string name;
    int time;
    int nsongs;
};
```

Here is the function where I believe the problem is:

```
map <string, Artist*> newArtist(Artist* a, Album* al, Song* s, string artist, string album, int track, map <string, Artist*> lib){
    if (lib.find(artist) == lib.end()){
        cout << "New Artist: " << artist << endl;
        a->name = artist;
        lib[artist] = a;
    } else if (lib.find(artist) != lib.end()){
        cout << "Old Artist: " << artist << endl;
    }
    if (lib.find(artist)->second->albums.find(album) == lib.find(artist)->second->albums.end()){
        cout << "New Album: " << album << endl;
        al->name = album;
        lib.find(artist)->second->albums[album] = al;
    } else if (lib.find(artist)->second->albums.find(album) != lib.find(artist)->second->albums.end()){
        cout << "Old Album: " << album << endl;
    }
    return lib;
}
```

This is what prints out. As you can see every single album is under every artist.

```
King Crimson
        A Russian Piano Recital
        Intergalactic Boogie Express
        Jazz Piano III (A Smithsonian Collection)
        Josef Hofmann & Ignace Jan Paderewski Play Liszt
        Larks' Tongues In Aspic
        Paderewski Plays Concert No. 1
        Three of a Perfect Pair
Larkins, Ellis
        A Russian Piano Recital
        Intergalactic Boogie Express
        Jazz Piano III (A Smithsonian Collection)
        Josef Hofmann & Ignace Jan Paderewski Play Liszt
        Larks' Tongues In Aspic
        Paderewski Plays Concert No. 1
        Three of a Perfect Pair
League of Crafty Guitarists
        A Russian Piano Recital
        Intergalactic Boogie Express
        Jazz Piano III (A Smithsonian Collection)
        Josef Hofmann & Ignace Jan Paderewski Play Liszt
        Larks' Tongues In Aspic
        Paderewski Plays Concert No. 1
        Three of a Perfect Pair
Lewin, Michael
        A Russian Piano Recital
        Intergalactic Boogie Express
        Jazz Piano III (A Smithsonian Collection)
        Josef Hofmann & Ignace Jan Paderewski Play Liszt
        Larks' Tongues In Aspic
        Paderewski Plays Concert No. 1
        Three of a Perfect Pair
Paderewski, Ignace
        A Russian Piano Recital
        Intergalactic Boogie Express
        Jazz Piano III (A Smithsonian Collection)
        Josef Hofmann & Ignace Jan Paderewski Play Liszt
        Larks' Tongues In Aspic
        Paderewski Plays Concert No. 1
        Three of a Perfect Pair
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: would you like to show us the error?

Comment: Okay I added the output.

Comment: I got it to work by removing the delete's for the object after the function. Idk if that means I have a memory leak

Comment: You can add your solution as answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this I needed to create the objects within the main program loop and I had to remove the statements where I deleted them.